# Non property assigned variable is delete-able

Tags: javascript, properties, attributes

I was reading [this article](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/) on the Javascript `delete` method, and tried this code:

```
function f(){
    var x = "abcd";
    console.log(delete x); //returns false, because x has DontDelete attribute
    y = "abcd";
    console.log(delete y); //returns true, but I didn't explicitly assign y as a property
}
```

This is strange, because I am not using property assignment for `y` (as in: `window.y="abcd";`), which the article [claims](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/#property_attributes) is how you make properties `delete`able.

Why does `y` not have the `DontDelete` attribute?

**UPDATE:**

In the answers below, it is claimed that y is deleteable merely because it is a property of the `window` object. That is not true. Consider the following snippet:

```
function f() {
    var functionx = "abcd";
    console.log(delete functionx); //returns false, because x has DontDelete attribute
    functiony = "abcd";
    console.log(delete functiony); //returns true, but I didn't explicitly assign functiony as a property to the window
}

//take 1
var globalx = "abcd";
console.log(this.globalx);//to prove x is a property of the global
console.log(delete globalx);//fails, even though x is a property of the window

//take 2
this.globaly = "abcd";
console.log(this.globaly);//to prove y is a property of the global
console.log(delete globaly);//succeeds, because I used property assignment

f();
```

In take 1, `globalx` is a property of the window, but it is still undeleteable. The criteria for whether `delete` will succeed is not whether the variable is a property of something (which is always true), but whether that property has a `DontDelete` attribute set.

Comment: When I [run the edited code](http://jsfiddle.net/kendfrey/jpF73/), I certainly don't get the result you describe. I think the given answers are still valid.

Comment: @KendallFrey You need to put the script in the body, not in an onLoad event. Here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jpF73/2/ Also, I accidentally missed the `var` next to `localx`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the expanded version of the second example:

```
window.y = "abcd";
console.log(delete window.y);
```

It's pretty obvious now what's happening.

If you don't use the `var` keyword, the interpreter assumes the variable is a property of the global object, (which is usually `window`), as shown in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kendfrey/Y4yj8/). Note that in the global scope, `this` is the same as the `window` object.

Re: Update:

Outside a function, a variable declared with `var` is defined as a **non-configurable** property of the global object. This is detailed in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var, where it says:

> Using `var` outside a function is optional; assigning a value to an undeclared variable implicitly declares it as a global variable (also a property of the global object). The difference is that a declared variable is a non-configurable property of the global object while an undeclared is configurable.

Declaring a variable inside a function does not assign it to a global property, but rather a local variable.

That explains the behaviour you're seeing when defining a variable in the global scope.

Comment: No, without `var` the parent scopes are searched - it has nothing to do with `this`. If the identifier is found nowhere, it is considered to be a global variable / property of the global object.

Answer (score 2):

`delete x` is invalid because it does not resolve to any object property.

`y` resolves to a property of the `window` object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete:

> delete *expression*
>
> where *expression* should evaluate to a property reference

Comment: Isn't `x` a property of the variable object of the current execution context?

Comment: @Asad That's an implementation detail, from js perspective it's just a variable. It's not a property of any object accessible to userland code.

Comment: I sort of get it, but then why does running `var x="abcd";console.log(delete x);` in the global context log false? When I use `var x`, x is still a property of the window object. Why is it undeleteable?

Comment: @Asad global variables created with `var` have `DontDelete` (I.E `configurable === false`... if you do `window.x = "abcd"`, it should work. See http://jsfiddle.net/yeJ2b/1/

Answer (score 1):

Variables in JavaScript [are declared using `var` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var). When you omit `var`, the interpreter starts looking for the closest scope in which the given variable is defined. If the given variable is not found, [it will be created as a new property on a global object](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/#undeclared_assignments).

This is exactly what happens here:

- Variable `y` is referenced and assigned a new value (`abcd`)
- Var `y` is not defined anywhere → new global property `y` is created and assigned the value (effectively `window.y = "abcd"`).
- As a result, `y` becomes property of the global object, which can be deleted.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My problem is that that not all properties of the global object can be deleted. See my update.